# HTML: Center Vertical Alignment of Two Lines of Text

Tags: html, css

Basically, this code places an image (223 x 83) at the left and two lines of text to the right of the image. The overall height of the entire box is 85px and width is 1024px.

How would I vertically align the text to make sure the two lines are vertically centered in the overall box? Is it possible to do this with this code without the usage of divs?

```
<tr><td><table><tr><td><table><tr><td>

<a href="#link">
<img src="linkToAnImage" style="width:223px; height:83px; border:1px #000000 solid;" align="left"/>
<span>Line 1 Content</span>
<br/>
<span>Line 2 Content</span>
</a>


</tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add style="display:block" to the span of line 1 content .

Comment: ^ that's kinda messy

Comment: Tried it, but margin to the left of the text to the image is now zero and margin-left, padding-left not working. margin-top works now though, but fixed 1 issue, caused another.

Comment: Basically, I need any way to be able to use margin-left and margin-top or padding-left and padding-bottom for the two lines of span text (in relation to the image at the left and top of content area at top), however we can get that working with divs or any other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since now most of the browsers support `display:flex`:

```
.valign-content-mid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and use your  tag as a wrapper

```
<a href="#link" class="valign-content-mid">
  <img src="linkToAnImage" style="width:223px; height:83px; border:1px #000000 solid"/>
  <span>
  Line 1 Content<br/>
  Line 2 Content
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: This breaks each span line into two lines, so into 4.

Answer (score 0):

Puth both span element inside div, as div is block level element and add style style="text-align: center;".

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<tr><td><table><tr><td><table><tr><td>

<a href="#link">
<img src="linkToAnImage" style="width:223px; height:83px; border:1px #000000 solid;" align="left"/>
<div style="text-align: center;"><span >Line 1 Content</span><br>
<span>Line 2 Content</span></div>

</a>


</tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr>
```

Comment: i think he just mentioned "without the usage of divs?"

Comment: I don't mind divs, but when Line 1 Content is more characters (longer) it breaks it into two lines then Line 2 Content gets pushed down to another new line outside the height of the box

Comment: It's working when I add width:1000px; to the div, but how do I add spacing above Line 1 Content? padding-top and margin-top not working within the Line 1 Content span.

Comment: Basically, I need any way to be able to use margin-left and margin-top or padding-left and padding-bottom for the two lines of span text (in relation to the image at the left and top of content area at top), however we can get that working with divs or any other way. Thanks.